# Microsoft InfoPath Error? Cannot open

Tags: infopath

Just wondering if anyone can help me with an InfoPath problem I've got. I have a form that I am unable to open, originally displaying the message below.

The form definition (.xsf) file contains elements, attributes, or structures that are not valid.

Error details:
The keyref 'ruleSet_41' does not resolve to a key for the Identity Constraint '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/solutionDefinition}ruleset_name_key'.
 
Line 1539, Position 3

--^

I have managed to clear this by removing ruleSet_41 from the manifest.xsf file but the message I am now receiving is shown below.

The following file is referenced in the .xsf file but is not part of the form: myschema.xsd

This is stopping me opening the form.

Does anyone have any ideas, anything would be much appreciated.

Many thanks, Jamie.

Comment: Did you rebuild the form after you made changes to manifest? Or did you just try and design the manifest directly?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the button that contains the RuleSetAction.

There would also look, open the file "myschema.xsd" will have been a reference to "ruleSet_41". Also delete it from the .xsd